# Converting from C++/CLI oldsyntax: How to and can this be automated?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, syntax, c++-cli

In the transition from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008 I started getting this error for my (managed) c++ projects:

```
warning D9035 : option 'clr:oldsyntax' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

How to I convert from the old syntax to the new one?

*Does anybody know when the old syntax actually becomes obsolete and cannot be used anymore?*

**EDIT:** (supplementary question)

Are there by any chance any tools for doing this conversion automatically?

Comment: There used to be a tool, but it's no longer available: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2006/12/07/managed-extensions-for-c-to-ccli-conversion-tool/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To change the Common Language Runtime support you open the properties dialog for your c++ project and select the node *Configuration Properties* -> *General*. Here you can make the change:

[image]

For how to upgrade the syntax I can recommend these two excellent MSDN articles:

- [Outline of Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235298(v=VS.90).aspx): This outline
  shows you examples of some of the
  changes in the language from Managed
  Extensions for C++ to Visual C++ 2008
- [Managed Extensions for C++ Syntax
  Upgrade Checklist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b23b94s7.aspx): This topic lists
  the syntactic differences between
  Managed Extensions for C++ and the
  new Visual C++ syntax